# Angular ngFor show limit item and click to show next

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm doing with ngFor but I want my ngFor to show just 3 items each page, and then when I click next it'll show next 3 items on another page, which mean page 1 show 3 items (1,2,3) page 2 show 3 items (4,5,6) and so on, just like when we search Google and click next or 'page 2' to show more result on page 2.
I'm using slice but it's not enough. I'm stucking with idea so I really need your help, also if you guys know some key word of this problem please let me know. Many thanks.

This is my *-component.html:

```
<section class="commentSection">
  <div class="comment" *ngFor="let item of reviewComments | slice:0:3">
      <div class="text">
        <div class="textContent" [innerHTML]="item.contentcomment"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        {{item.nameReviwer}} | {{item.date}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This is my *-component.ts":

```
getComments(bookId) { //get comment follow bookId
    this.bookService.getComment(bookId).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.reviewComments = res as ReviewComment[];
      console.log('List Comment: ', this.reviewComments);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

This is my *.service.ts

```
getComment(bookId: string): Observable<any> {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-type': 'application/json' });
        return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/getcmtbook/' + bookId, { headers: headers }).catch(err => {
          return Observable.throw(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: Provide all related code

Comment: Do you want that should work like pagination?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale so that is Key word. Thank you very much, I'll loking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler and effective approach to your problem is using [Angular Material Paginator](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview)

The examples mentioned in the documentation are self explanatory and easy to follow.

Also the Ngx-Pagination is the quick and easy way.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination

Comment: This really is the Key word I'm looking for, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *[`Mat-Paginator`](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api)* component in the forloop:

HTML Code:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of collection">
    <h3>{{obj}}</h3>
</div>
<mat-paginator [length]="100" [pageSize]="defaultRecords" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" (page)="pageEvent = $event; onPaginateChange($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';
/**
 * @title Paginator
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'paginator-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'paginator-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['paginator-overview-example.css'],
})
export class PaginatorOverviewExample implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  temp: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];

  collection : any[] = []

  defaultRecords: any = 5;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.collection = this.temp.slice(0, this.defaultRecords);
  }
  onPaginateChange(data) {
    this.collection = this.temp.slice(0, data.pageSize);
  }
}
```

[`Updated_Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xurger)

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's not like my expectation. I want it show just 3 items(a,b,c) on a single page and next 3 items(d,e,f) on page 2 but your solution is more like Show more.

Comment: @TLVF2627 That means do you want pagination for the list?

Comment: @TLVF2627 Updated answer please check

Comment: Thanks for your help, "Pagination" is the key word I'm looking for.

Comment: I mean Paginator is the thing sloved my problem.